# Opencart 2.0 get config value from admin or frontend also Permission

Tags: php, opencart

Is it possible in opencart 2.0 to get the value from the settings.
For example as it was in previous opencart versions I could store value to database via settings, thus I did not need any model file to write to database and then from anywhere I could get the value by:

```
$this->config->get('key_that_you_need');
```

...
Now this still works but only when in controller.
What I need is to get the value even when I'm in template file (*.tpl)

When I want to use this in *.tpl file I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Loader::$config
```

same situation applies for permissions... now you can't use this example from template:

```
<?php if($this->user->hasPermission('access','catalog/attribute')) { ?>
```

...however it is still functional in controller file

Does anyone know if it is possible or some workaround ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using it in your template in the first place - You should be setting the data for the in your controller and passing that to the template. However You can do this pretty easily. Firstly, you need to bring the `$config` variable into the template and then call it directly, not use `$this`

```
<?php
global $config;
$somevar = $config->get('key_that_you_need');
?>
```

Not tested but should still work just fine

Comment: Thank you Jay this worked for the $config thing like a charm. I will try to implement it through controller though as you mentioned, however how it is with the permissions ? I tried the same approach as for config but without luck. Can I call user in template and in template ask/check if the user has the permission ? (if user > has permission(catalog/articles) > do something ?)

Comment: The "User" object is admin side only. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, only admin side.

Comment: `global $registry; $user = $registry->get('user');`

Comment: @JayGilford how to set in latest OpenCart 2.3.0.2? please check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830286/how-to-setting-global-variables-in-opencart-2-3-0-2