# How to setting global variables in OpenCart 2.3.0.2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

When I want to set a global variable in template (`.tpl` files), I just use `global` in opencart 2.2 or older version.

**For example:**

```
<?php global $config; if($config->get('my_options')== 1) { ?>....<?php } ?>
```

but, **it does not work in Latest OpenCart 2.3.0.2**

Because predefined `global $config` in controller rather inconvenient (we have use config value in many template file).
Hopefully someone with more experience will have an answer to this problem.

Comment: checkout this links http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=166278,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least code you will get defining them as constants in config.php or admin/config.php, depending on where you will need them. This will make these constants immediately available throughout the catalog or admin context.

Another way is by using $this->config in controllers to get key/values out of the setting table into your models or controllers.